# Python, AttributeError: 'PlayerPaddle' object has no attribute 'update'

Tags: python

```
    import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

class PlayerPaddle(object):
   def __init__(self, screensize):

    self.screensize = screensize

    self.position_x = int(screensize[0]*0.5)
    self.position_y = int(screensize[1]*0.8)

    self.width  = 10
    self.height = 4

    self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.position_x - (self.width*0.5),
                            self.position_y - (self.height*0.5),
                            self.width, self.height)
    self.color = (100, 200, 200)

    self.speed = 5
    self.direction = 0

    def update(self):
        self.position_x += self.direction * self.speed

    def render(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, self.color, self.rect, 0)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,0), self.rect, 1)

def main():
    pygame.init()

    screensize = (600, 700)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screensize)

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    player_paddle = PlayerPaddle(screensize)

    running = True

    while running:
        clock.tick(64)


        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                running = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player_paddle.direction = 1
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player_paddle.direction = -1
            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player_paddle.direction = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player_paddle.direction = 0

        player_paddle.update()

        screen.fill((100, 100, 100))

        player_paddle.render(screen)

        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()

main()
```

Sorry for long code.. But I'm getting so frustrated. Why am i getting "'PlayerPaddle' object has no attribute 'update'"
Error !?

For what i have been able to understand its my `def update(self)` function that is returning null or smth.. But how is that? Is it in my eventhandler that the error is? Is it updating the position wrong?

Comment: Is that your real indentation? It's important in Python...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your indentation is off.  Your methods `update` and `render` are indented inside the `__init__` method.  Move them out one indentation level.

Comment: Wooow are you F-ing kidding me... I have been strugling with this bug over the past 2 days.... They should really make the indentations more clear. Anyway! Thanks alot! @BrenBarn